# Realtime crypto table with React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datatable, datatables, next.js

**Introdution**

I am working on react project where table is rendered whenever `WebSocket` data is available.

Data at time1:

```
[{Name:"Coinbase",Price:5510, Pair:"BTC/USD"},{Name:"Coinmama",Price:5508, Pair:"BTC/USD"}]
```

Data at time2 :

```
[{Name:"Coinbase",Price:5511, Pair:"BTC/USD"},{Name:"Coinmama",Price:5508, Pair:"BTC/USD"}]
```

Problems with this approach is that always full table rendered.

I was looking for the help to build such table which can have ability to update only changed data (like row 1 should be updated on time2). For example [here implemented](http://linecoins.info)

**Question**

From my research i have not found any useful information to follow, but

`Next.js` like framework are used by `Binance`, i assume the realtime tables functionality can be achieved along with others.

Does framework like Next.js would be the answer?

Any reference, example or help will be appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Comment: it would help if downvoters care to explain the cause of downvoting, so that i can update accordingly.thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using `Next.js` you need to realize first which data will be preloaded and rendered on the server.

You can preload tickers with REST API, then render them on the server. After your page is displayed in a browser, you can use websockets to listen for changes and update the table.

Here is [an example](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/master/examples/with-socket.io) how to use `Next.js` with `socket.io`, this can be a good starting point for you.